# BizTalk 2010 EDIAssembler is missing to write segment delimiter on SE segment

Tags: batch-file, biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

We have a custom batching orchestration which batches incoming EDI transaction sets (BizTalk server 2010).

When sending out this batched message it will be assembled by the EDI Assembler on the send port. We noticed that on some of the SE segments the EDI assembler is not putting any segment delimiter and writing the next segment(ST or GE) and this is causing issues in the down stream applications.

Example:-

`SE*89*7025236ST*837*7025237*005010X223A2~`

`SE*87*0118GE*2*13~`

How can we resolve this?

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: Have you checked that your individual messages are correct, prior to batching them?

Comment: Yes they do have the segment delimiter ~

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little bit on your custom batching orchestration? Is this something which you encounter only with certain batches or always?

Comment: HI Pieter, its an aggregator orchestration which batches multiple disassembled EDI 837 xml. It adds the required headers before sending the batched message and this will be assembled by the EDI assembler. This behavior is consistent with some specific 837s. But when I try to batch just that one 837, I don't see this issue, its just when it batches more than one , it misses the segment delimiter. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you constructing an X12InterchangeXml message?

Comment: Yes John. That's right. We are facing the same issue even when we use the Microsoft EDI Batching orchestration to do the batching.